# Ubuntu popups not showing any text anymore

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm having problems with my Ubuntu (running on a VM). This is what I get when I try to delete or move files in VSCode for example. The popup window doesn't show any text anymore. How can I solve this problem? I tried upgrading my nvidia drivers but nothing changed.

[image]

The VSCode window as well does not show the text correctly.

[image]

Also when I hover on a button or a checkbox, it becomes transparent and shows what's underneath, so the issue must be related to a graphics driver or display configurations.

[image]

Comment: Could be that a font used in the popup is missing. Install in the VM fonts that the underlying OS uses.

Comment: I did but still the same issue.

Comment: Does anybody has an answer on that? Did you find a solution @Samir?